# linux suse 10 apache related

Tags: linux, sles

My application is using apache and the server is integrated with siteminder. I am using suse 10, when I run `cat` command I am getting the following error:

```
 cat: symbol lookup error: /opt/netegrity/siteminder/webagent/lib/libbtunicode.so: undefined symbol: pthread_once
```

Even after I run clear command am getting this error. Can you tell me what the reason could be?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer to your question:

If an executable that you run gives a symbol lookup error, it probably means that the linker is attempting to use a version of a shared library that doesn't have everything in it that it should. This probably means that it is not looking in the right places, although it could mean that something was incorrectly compiled for your system.

On linux, ldd(1) is used to show which libraries are being linked into an executable, /etc/ld.so.conf is used to specify where the linker looks for libraries, and ldconfig(8) is used to rebuild the cache to the more recent shared libraries. Furthermore if you look in these man pages, you will see mention of relevant environment variables.

However, presumably what you really want to know is how to fix it. In order to advise an approach, it would be useful to know something about the installation process of siteminder. Does it, for example, use a chroot environment or some other special environment creation startup?

Comment: i haven't istalled the siteminder, can you tell me how to know its environment